# What is the fastest way to convert a server time (C#) to moment.js?

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, momentjs

Right now I'm converting everything to a json ISO 8601 string, and then on the client side to moment.js by using `moment(json.dateTime)`.

This means moment.js needs to parse a string for every date (might be in the thousands). Is there any more efficient way to convert the datetimes to clientside moment.js? E.g. using an integer?

Comment: Date/Time is tricky.  Use the standard methods and avoid a lot of issues.  This is the best approach.

Comment: You might want to look at the Moment.js documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-offset/